# Is there a way to disable django models and auth?

Tags: django

I newie in Django but I really like it and I have to work with raw SQL and I want to disable all django apps and use only with rest framework. I tried it but it doesnt work and I want to know if there is any way to disable Django models and auth and that things.

Actualization:

I want to disble the django models because i already have a database an i want to use raw sql with django rest framework but all needs django models.

##### The error I have:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/

Django Version: 4.0.8
Python Version: 3.10.8
Installed Applications:
['rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
[]



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 497, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 414, in initial
    self.perform_authentication(request)
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 324, in perform_authentication
    request.user
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 227, in user
    self._authenticate()
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 390, in _authenticate
    self._not_authenticated()
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\request.py", line 400, in _not_authenticated
    if api_settings.UNAUTHENTICATED_USER:
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 225, in __getattr__
    val = perform_import(val, attr)
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 166, in perform_import
    return import_from_string(val, setting_name)
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 177, in import_from_string
    return import_string(val)
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string
    return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 15, in cached_import
    import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\models.py", line 131, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\JUANXXIII_LAB3\Desktop\djangoapp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 132, in __new__
    raise RuntimeError(

Exception Type: RuntimeError at /hello/
Exception Value: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for core project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-3-3ohr&v#q-)8a%mp+qf1h0!2$_nd2&*hpor-!8@d(f+lsqb)+'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # 'django.contrib.auth',
    # 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    # 'django.contrib.sessions',
    # 'django.contrib.messages',
    # 'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                # 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                # 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    # },
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    # },
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    # },
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    # },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

urls.py

```
"""core URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
# from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class HelloView (APIView):
    def get(self):
        return 'Hello world!'

urlpatterns = [
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
    path('hello/', HelloView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to disable those stuffs as they constitute to as what DJANGO really is .... But Django has ways to work with raw sql ...check this if it helps  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: How is it not working are you getting an error? What have you tried? Please post more information in order to make your question more clear.

Comment: I already edited it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

you cant disable auth model if u are trying to disable auth model but u can create ur own custom user model [Django documentation for customizing the user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/)
this link will help u to customize the django auth model...